# how to pass Map in camel context in jbpm component

Tags: apache-camel, jbpm

look at the location [JBPMComponentIntegrationTest](https://github.com/bibryam/camel-jbpm/blob/master/component/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/jbpm/JBPMComponentIntegrationTest.java)

```
.setHeader(JBPMConstants.PARAMETERS, constant(map))
```

so them map is passed as map in java route.

If i want to pass the same via xml is there a way ?

```
            <camel:setHeader headerName="CamelJBPMParameters">
            <camel:constant>????</camel:constant>
        </camel:setHeader>
```

I could not find any example over internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a spring context you could simply initialize the map then reference it in your constant file.  I am not 100% familiar with the xml camel constructs but it should look similar to this:

```
<camelContext id="myContext"  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
            <setHeader headerName="theHeader">
                <!-- not sure if the ref keyword is valid might have to adjust syntax -->
                <constant ref="maps" />      
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="mock:result"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>

<property name="maps">
    <map>
        <entry key="Key 1" value="1" />
        <entry key="Key 2" value="2" />
        <entry key="Key 3" value="3" />
    </map>
</property>
```